# Responsive Bootstrap nav menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So I want to create a responsive menu, on a desktop my navbar is essentially 3 links and 3 small pictures which are also links.

When I move to a small screen, I want the 3 small pictures to stay as they are, but to place the text links into a drop down menu.

Here is my code for at the minute which is good for a desktop screen:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="search"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="checkout"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="home"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So this is good for a big screen.

I want to take the top 3 items and instead of hiding them on a small/xs screen I want them to move into a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/Zrpk5/3/)**

I have created a dropdown which will be showing for `sm` and `xs` devices.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown visible-xs visible-sm">
             <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
             <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="search"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="checkout"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="home"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you can see the header will change its layout based on the size of the screen, so if you have your content and everything else changing layout too is it the cleanest/most efficient way to keep using `visible/hidden` to change the layout, I've seen `@media` used also but it looks just as code-heavy.